# Headless Chrome run with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");

        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        //chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");

        final DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);


        final URL url = new URL("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");
        final WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
```

fails as:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Unable to parse remote response:
>
> ## Not Found

Any idea why?

Followed: [How to connect to Chromium Headless using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836422/how-to-connect-to-chromium-headless-using-selenium/43394396)

Answer (score 5):

What are the versions of your Chrome browser, chromedriver and Selenium? I tried with:

1. Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. chromedriver 2.33
3. Selenium 3.6.0

The following code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/pathTo/chromedriver);

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Note: In current versions of Selenium and ChromeDriver replace:

```
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

with

```
    chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
```

Ref: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setHeadless-boolean-
Also you must set Window size otherwise it renders in mobile mode and you may not get certain elements in the page.

```
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1200x600");
```

Tested on chromedriver 2.42.591071 with Selenium 3.14.0

The output:

```
The Internet
```

Take a look to [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) about the browser support versions.

Comment: Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit), ubuntu, Selenium 3.6.0, chromedriver 3.6.0 - too

Comment: @ses the current last version of chromedriver is the 2.33 :)

Comment: ok. will check. for me it comes from : import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver.. ok: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: I found the correct format to be `addArguments("window-size=1200,600")`

Answer (score 1):

```
options.addArguments("headless");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

This worked for me. Chromedriver Version:2.37