# Can a backend web service use selenium with a headless Chromium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-services, chromium

I'm developing a chatbot for a school project, which will utilise a web service in the backend, intending to deploy it onto a third party cloud server host such as Heroku.

The web service will be doing periodic web scraping in realtime. I was developing with BeautifulSoup until I discover dynamically loaded content in the pages I need to scrape, so I've to switch to Selenium.

The problem is that Selenium requires a browser, but the cloud server doesn't have a GUI and probably doesn't allow installation of applications too.

So one solution I thought of is to use Chromium, a portable version of Chrome which doesn't need installation, in headless mode, which doesn't need a GUI.

- [How to connect to Chromium Headless using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836422/how-to-connect-to-chromium-headless-using-selenium)
- [Can Selenium Webdriver open browser windows silently in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background)

I'm still a long way from figuring out how to deploy onto a cloud hosting server, let alone test my idea, so I thought to just seek professional input in advance. Will my web service be permitted by host servers to run in this manner?

Comment: You first need to tell us what kind of service do you have. A virtual machine or just a lambda/function service?

Comment: Just a folder of some compiled Python scripts, possibly with Chromium and chromedriver inside. That'll be deployed onto the third party cloud server host where it'll run as a service, as far as I can understand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Well, I can confirm that selenium is able to open a browser in headless mode. You just need to pass some startup parameters. But also, unfortunately, as far as I know, a headless browser sometimes doesn't have full functionalities. The best choice could be using xvfb to create a virtual GUI environment.